# Assignment operator=

Tags: c++, overloading

Suppose I have a class called `Complex` with 2 parameters real and imag. I want to overload the `=(assignment) operator` so that I could copy the value from the real parameter and assign it to an int.
If my main would look something like;

```
Complex z(1, 2);
int a = z;
```

I want a to be equal to 1.
How can I implement this function/method?

Comment: It looks like a bad idea. Why not be explicit? `int a = z.real();`?

Comment: C has no overloads, tag removed

Comment: If anything, an implicit conversion to a non-complex type should capture the modulus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use cast operator:

```
//Declaraion
class Complex {
  operator int();
}

//Definition
Complex::operator int() {
  return real_number;
}
```

Cast operator can implicitly convert a class instance to a certain type that is defined. It is a handy tool, but sometimes can be dangerous and vulnerable, and hard to debug.

Comment: In this case it is best not to implement. The give away is in the name "Complex" number

Comment: I'd rather avoid this. Name it alike: Complex::to_int()

Comment: @mfro clearly `Complex::real()` would make more sense. Otherwise you have to read the documentation to figure out what the method is doing.

Comment: @juanchopanza: look at the original post. I understood the OP wanted to have an int?

Comment: @mfro Yes and? OP wants to get the real part of a complex number. OP hasn't said anything about the types of the actual data members.

Comment: @mfro well if it only has to be "an int", then `Complex::operator int() {return 42;}` is just as good, no?

Comment: @juanchopanza note I was replying to mfro and not you. I agree "real" is a much better name.

Comment: @immibis Got it, sorry for the confusion. In conclusion, `int to_int()` is almost as bad as the operator. It is more explicit, but that doesn't really help, if it doesn't express what the int corresponds to.

Answer (score 2):

When you define the assignment operator you are instructing the compiler on what to do when a value of possibly a different type is assigned to and instance of your class.

In this case instead you want to define what to do when an instance of your class is assigned to a variable of a different non-class type and this is not possible however. In other words it's the receiving instance that defines what to do in case of an assignment and you can customize this only for class types.

Something quite similar is instead to define how an instance of your class should be convertible to another type, e.g. how to convert a complex to an integer, and this conversion will be used also in case of assignment:

```
 struct complex {
     double real, imag;
     ...
     operator int () const { return int(real); }
 };
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't ideal to have code that reads as an assignment of types from different equivalence classes. It is correct that one should use casting instead, but the casting must be made **explicit** in C++11:

```
struct Complex {
     double r, i;
     ...
     explicit operator int () const { return int(r); }
 };

 Complex c = { 1.1, 2.2 };
 float a = c;        // fails with explicit
 float a = (float)c; // fails with explicit
 int a = c;          // fails with explicit
 int a = (int)c;     // compiles with explicit
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to define a class for `complex`? It's part of standard library

Even you can see `<complex>` (`#include <complex>`) to find the operators and definitions overloaded

See more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/complex/complex/)